# Convert integer to float without precision lost

Tags: c, oracle, math, floating-point, int

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i=1; i <= 10000; ++i)
    {
        printf("i= %.4lf\n", (float)i/10000);
    }
}
```

Will it print always 10000 different numbers?

```
i= 0.0002
i= 0.0003
i= 0.0004
i= 0.0005
. . .
i= 0.9995
i= 0.9996
i= 0.9997
i= 0.0001
i= 0.9998
i= 0.9999
i= 1.0000
```

I want to insert money values on a Oracle database and need an 
accuracy of four decimal places. I have heard tha NUMBER(19,4) data type guaranteethis accuracy in Oracle, but need to be sure that it is get in my C program.

My insert statement will be somethig simiar to this:

```
INSERT INTO PRUEBA VALUES(i/10000);
```

It is posible to loss precision in this operation?

Thanks, Jose Luis.

Comment: **Do not use floating point for currency or other precise values.**

Comment: @Oalf Floating-point decimal is a very acceptable choice of representing currency.

Comment: I found this somewhere on SO, maybe it helps you: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). I forget which post it was...

Comment: @chux, only acceptable if you don't mind that float cannot represent all values exactly, so the result will be errors in the results of calculations.

Comment: @user3629249 no type can "represent all values exactly". It would be illuminating to learn of an example currency error that would not be handled well in decimal floating point.

Comment: @chux - What do C `float` values have to do with these "decimal floating point" values you're talking about?  To quote a really easy-to-find Google hit:  (http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/14/currency-rounding-errors/)  "When doing any kind of calculation with currency, accuracy is extremely important. **And floating point numbers (floats and doubles) don’t have an accurate enough representation to prevent rounding errors from accumulating when doing arithmetic with monetary values**."

Comment: @Andrew Henle I did not mention `float`.  My comment was about "Do not use floating point for currency".  Floating point decimal types such as [decimal64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) and their kin well handle the issues brought up by the article cited.  The author calls them "built-in decimal type", but these can be a type of floating point based on 10 rather than the more common 2.   Perhaps you are thinking "floating point" implies only base 2 types like [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: @Andrew Henle  `double` have at least 10 decimal digits of accuracy - by spec., commonly 15+.  The primary issue of using binary base FP for money is one of conversion to/from base 10 text and incorrect rounding, not of limited accuracy.

Comment: @chux - The problem is much more fundamental than that.  The number of significant decimal digits doesn't really matter.  Look up catastrophic cancellation and loss of significance.

Answer (score 2):

Will it print always 10000 different numbers? --> Yes - with this code.

Will `(float)i/100000)` it print always 100000 different numbers? --> Maybe.

This will work until code reaches `float` precision of about 6+ significant decimal digits.   It depends on `FLT_DIG` which is `6` or larger.

---

"accuracy of four decimal places." is trickier.  `float` is a *floating* point number.  With it you have 6+ significant digits like 1234560000.0, not 4 digits after the decimal point - which may require "fixed point".

---

If code needs all results correct to 19 digits, a different approach is needed.  Even `double` may not meet coding goals as it is at least 10 and often 15-17 digits of significance.

Using Oracle `NUMBER(19,4)` obliges use of a 65+ bit number. (at least 64 bit precision, 1 bit sign).   No standard C integer/floating-point type can alwasy meet this.  Unless code uses some structure, I see no solution that would always prevent loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use (implicit) fixed-point. Just keep representing your numbers as integers, by dropping the decimal point. When you need the values in computations, restore them by multiplying by 0.0001.

32 bits integer will allow the range `-214748.3648` to `214748.3647`, quite probably too limited.

64 bits integer will allow the range `-922337203685477.5808` to `922337203685477.5807`.

Note that this is more accuracy than what can be stored in double precision floats, so you should make up your mind about the real range that you need and the arithmetic operations to be supported.